# Dummy coding of linear regression, intercept and constraint

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-encoding, intercept

Let the following multilevel problem, where we try to predict the credit card balance of individuals $y_i$:

$$
x_{i 1}= \begin{cases}1 & \text { if } i \text { th person is from the South } \\ 0 & \text { if } i \text { th person is not from the South },\end{cases}
$$

and the second should be

$$
x_{i 2}= \begin{cases}1 & \text { if } i \text { th person is from the West } \\ 0 & \text { if } i \text { th person is not from the West. }\end{cases}
$$

Then both of these variables can be used in the regression equation, in order to obtain the model
$$
y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{i 1}+\beta_2 x_{i 2}+\epsilon_i= \begin{cases}\beta_0+\beta_1+\epsilon_i & \text { if } i \text { th person is from the South } \\ \beta_0+\beta_2+\epsilon_i & \text { if } i \text { th person is from the West } \\ \beta_0+\epsilon_i & \text { if } i \text { th person is from the East. }\end{cases}
$$

My problem now is to solve by linear regression under the problem that adding the intercept will add a lot of colinearity between the column vectors. One solution is to add one constraint:

$$
\beta_0 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0
$$

And use restricted least square. But what is the interpretation of adding this constraint ? (Outside of the technical reason) I suppose that we cannot say anymore that $\beta_0$ can be interpreted as the average credit card balance for individuals from the east

$$
y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{i 1}+\beta_2 x_{i 2}+\epsilon_i= \begin{cases}-\beta_2+\epsilon_i & \text { if } i \text { th person is from the South } \\ -\beta_1+\epsilon_i & \text { if } i \text { th person is from the West } \\ -\beta_1 - \beta_2+\epsilon_i & \text { if } i \text { th person is from the East. }\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you use a single column for each dummy variable, this wouldn't induce collinearity. Collinearity arises when for $n$ categories you use precisely $n$ columns (one-hot way) so that sum of these columns produces a column of ones, which is a multiple of intercept column. In your case there would be combinations like

```
0 1
0 0
1 1
1 0
```

which don't sum up into a constant (unless those categories are linearly dependent in the first place).

Also note that imposing constraint $\beta_0 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0$ and substituting for $\beta_0$ in the regression formula produces $y_i = \beta_1(x_{i1} - 1) + \beta_2(x_{i2} - 1) + \epsilon_i$ which amounts to re-coding categories as 0 and -1 and dropping intercept term.